# Implementing code in 'R'?

Tags: r

Suppose I had the following data set.

```
Index-----Country------Age------Time-------Response
---------------------------------------------------
1------------------Germany-----------20-30----------15-20------------------1

2------------------Germany-----------20-30----------15-20------------------NA

3------------------Germany-----------20-30----------15-20------------------1

4------------------Germany-----------20-30----------15-20------------------0

5------------------France--------------20-30----------30-40------------------1
```

And I would like to fill in the NA based on the criteria listed below

1. Find all exact matches of Country, Age and Time. ie. Index 1, 3 and 4
2. Select at random 1 value from the Response column of these matching
   rows. ie 1,1 or 0
3. Replace the NA with this new value

And I would like it to continue on in the same manner for the rest of the NA's in the data set.

I'm new to 'R' and can't figure out how to code this.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: What do you want done with all the minus signs in your data?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach using the "data.table" package:

```
DT <- data.table(mydf, key = "Country,Age,Time")
DT[, R2 := ifelse(is.na(Response), sample(na.omit(Response), 1), 
                  Response), by = key(DT)]
DT
#    Index Country   Age  Time Response R2
# 1:     5  France 20-30 30-40        1  1
# 2:     6  France 20-30 30-40       NA  2
# 3:     7  France 20-30 30-40        2  2
# 4:     1 Germany 20-30 15-20        1  1
# 5:     2 Germany 20-30 15-20       NA  1
# 6:     3 Germany 20-30 15-20        1  1
# 7:     4 Germany 20-30 15-20        0  0
```

Similarly, in base R, you could try `ave`:

```
within(mydf, {
  R2 <- ave(Response, Country, Age, Time, FUN = function(x) {
    ifelse(is.na(x), sample(na.omit(x), 1), x)
  })
})
```

---

Sorry, forgot to share the sample data I was working with:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Index = 1:7, Country = c("Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "France", "France", "France"), Age = c("20-30", 
"20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30"), Time = c("15-20", 
"15-20", "15-20", "15-20", "30-40", "30-40", "30-40"), Response = c(1L, 
NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, NA, 2L)), .Names = c("Index", "Country", "Age", 
"Time", "Response"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```